# How to get something written to MySQL error log without restart

Tags: mysql, error-log

I want to cause the MySQL 5.5 error log to be written to at will without a service stop or start. Note that I do not care **what** gets written to the error log, as long as **something** gets written.

I tried running a bad query and setting a nonexistent system variable, but those actions do not seem to generate an entry in the error log.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just noticed that stopping the slave writes to the error log. Anything simpler?

Comment: Linux or Windows ? (Please say Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bad queries and other invalid actions typically only write to the error log when there's not a client connection to write the error to... such as when a thread that isn't a client thread encounters an error... or from the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html).

From within a scheduled event, [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) can be used to throw errors and warnings that will be written to MySQL's error log.  And, of course, you can "schedule" an event to run only once, right now.

```
mysql> USE test;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE EVENT test_error_log ON SCHEDULE AT NOW() ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE 
       DO SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'hi from the error log';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

$ sudo tail /usr/local/mysql/data/hostname.err
--8<-- snip --8<--
150121 14:25:06 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: [sqlbot@%][test.test_error_log] hi from the error log
```

Alternately, there's a 3rd party [user-defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html) `log_error()` that can write to the error log: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_log

That's assuming you're not "really" wanting to trigger MySQL to politely close and reopen the log file... this is done with [`FLUSH ERROR LOGS;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you're using MySQL 5.6 set the [log_warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_warnings) variable to 2 with

```
SET GLOBAL log_warnings = 2;
```

> If the value is greater than 1, the server logs aborted connections and access-denied errors for new connection attempts

Then simply try to connect to the server with the wrong password.

As of MySQL 5.7.2 the log_warnings variable is deprecated and [log_error_verbosity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity) should be used. Here the default is 3, so usually you don't have to change this to have above said behaviour of logging failed access attempts.